# How to Pass Multiple Objects via the Pipeline Between Two Functions in Powershell

Tags: email, loops, object, powershell, smtp

I am attempting to pass a list of objects from one function to another, one by one.

**First function**: generate a list of users (objects) near expiry;
   **Second function**: send an email to each user (object)

The first function works fine and outputs a group of objects (or so it would seem) and the second function will accept input and email a single user without issue.

Issues arise only when multiple objects are passed from the first function to the second.

**Relevant code snippets are below:**

The First function creates a custom object for each located user and adds it to an array, which is then outputted in the end block. Below is an extremely simplified snippet of the code with the essential object creation step:

```
Function 01
{
    #param block goes here etc...

    Foreach ($user in $users)
    {
        $userOutput = @()

        $userTable = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            name = $User.Name
            SamAccountName = $User.SamAccountName
            emailAddress = $User.EmailAddress
            expired = $user.PasswordExpired
            expiryDate = $ExpiryDate.ToShortDateString()
            daysTillExpiry = $daysTillExpiry
            smtpRecipientAddress = $User.EmailAddress
            smtpRecipientName = $User.Name
        }

        $userOutput += $userTable
    }

    Write-Output $userOutput
}
```

I have also tried writing each custom object ($userTable) straight to the console within each iteration of the Foreach (users) loop.

The Second function accepts pipeline input for a number of matching parameters from the first function, e.g:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$smtpRecipientName
```

The second function also calls a third function designed specifically to send smtp mail and contains no loops, it just takes the current object from the pipeline and deals with it.

I haven't included the full code for either mail function because it is largely irrelevant. I just want to know whether the objects outputted from the first function can be dealt with one-by-one by the second.

At present, the mail function deals with the first object passed to it, and no others.

**Update:**

This is what I have in mind (but the second function only deals with the last object that was piped in:

```
Function Test-UserExp
{
    $iteration = 0

    For ($i=0;$i -le 9;$i++)
    {
        $iteration ++
        $userTable = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            expiryDate = "TestExpDate_$iteration"
            daysTillExpiry = "TestDaysTillExpiry_$iteration"
            smtpRecipientAddress = "TestSMTPRecipientAddress_$iteration"
            smtpRecipientName = "TestSMTPRecipientName_$iteration"
        }

        $userTable
    }
}

Function Test-MailSend
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$expiryDate,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$daysTillExpiry,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$smtpRecipientAddress,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$smtpRecipientName
    )

    Write-Host 'Output from Test-MailSend:'

    $expiryDate
    $daysTillExpiry
    $smtpRecipientAddress  
    $smtpRecipientName


}
```

Comment: Guessing you should convert your functions to [Filters](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-functions.html) so they accept pipeline input and process as piped maybe?

Comment: As I mentioned: you need `process {}` block wrapped around the part where you try to read parameters passed from pipeline. Without it - your `Test-MailSend` function will have only `end {}` block, so only last object piped from first command will be processed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: if you want to process objects in a pipeline, one at the time, do not kill experience by collecting all the objects - that's only necessary if you intend to do something about whole collection at some point. If not than just output objects as soon as you get them:

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        name = $User.Name
        SamAccountName = $User.SamAccountName
        emailAddress = $User.EmailAddress
        # ...
    }
}
```

In your case you output whole collection at the end. That's hardly a *pipeline* experience if you would ask me.

For the second command: if you intend to create parameter for each property, just leave the part 'ValueFromPipeline' out. Otherwise you may end up with whole object converted to string... If you want to take an object as a whole, leave out 'ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName' and specify correct type. And make sure you have `process {}` wrapped around the code that uses parameters taken from pipeline.

And finally: why would you write a function to send mails? You have `Send-MailMessage`, so unless you do something this cmdlet doesn't cover, you probably don't need hand-crafted replacement...

Answer (score 1):

In function 1 you want to create the array before the ForEach loop, so you aren't re-creating the array every iteration.

In the param block for the second function, you want to declare the parameter as an array of strings, not just a string.

Finally, when accepting pipeline input for the second function you will need to use the Begin, Process, and End blocks.  The part of the function that repeats for each item should be in the Process block.
Here is a short working sample below:

```
Function fun1{
    $users = @(1,2,3)
    $userOutput = @()
    Foreach ($user in $users){
        $userTable = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            emailAddress = "$user@blah.com"
        }
        $userOutput += $userTable
    }
    $userOutput
}
Function fun2{
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeLine=$true)]
        [String[]]$Recipients
    )
    begin{}
    process{
        ForEach ($Recipient in $Recipients){
            $_
        }
    }
    end{}
}
fun1 | Select emailAddress | fun2
```

This will give you the output below:

```
emailAddress                                                                                                                                                     
------------                                                                                                                                                     
1@blah.com                                                                                                                                                       
2@blah.com                                                                                                                                                       
3@blah.com
```

Here is a great breakdown of how the Begin/Process/End blocks work in PowerShell http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh413265.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
function Set-UserExpiry {
    1..10 | foreach {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ExpiryDate           = "TestExpDate_$_"
            DaysTillExpiry       = "TestDaysTillExpiry_$_"
            SmtpRecipientAddress = "TestSMTPRecipientAddress_$_"
            SmtpRecipientName    = "TestSMTPRecipientName_$_"
        }
    }
}

function Test-UserExpiry {
    param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]$ExpiryDate,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]$DaysTillExpiry,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]$SmtpRecipientAddress,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]$SmtpRecipientName
    )

    process {
        Write-Output 'Output from Test-MailSend:'
        $expiryDate
        $daysTillExpiry
        $smtpRecipientAddress  
        $smtpRecipientName
        Write-Output ''
    }
}

Set-UserExpiry | Test-UserExpiry
```